# Error on MongoDB daemon errno:10050 failed to run mongod

Tags: mongodb

When I try to run MongoDB on Windows 64bit I receive this error:

```
C:\>mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2772 port=27017 dbpat
h=/data/db 64-bit host=wirelan-HM
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.7, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] git version: 875033920e8869d284f32119413543f
a475227bf
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(ma
jor=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB
_VERSION=1_42
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] options: {}
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Tue Aug 14 19:26:12 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recov
ery needed
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10050 U
na operaci├│n socket encontr├│ una red inactiva. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] now exiting
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 dbexit:
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets..
.
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Aug 14 19:26:13 dbexit: really exiting now
```

First error was the folder `/data/db`. I solved that. But from errno:10050 there is no information on Google... Can anybody solve this?

Comment: what happens when you explicitly tell your `mongod` what IP address to bind to? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/

Comment: i try to mongod with a config.conf but still same error i bind_ip 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that mongod has to be openned with administrator privileges in windows 7... right click on mongod.exe and open as administrator

probably shoud better use the windows prompt in admin mode... search in Start cmd right click open as admin

dont forget to create C:\data\db dir

tnx all

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows Sockets Error:

WSAENETDOWN 10050 - Network is down.
A socket operation encountered a dead network. This could indicate a serious failure of the network system (that is, the protocol stack that the Windows Sockets DLL runs over), the network interface, or the local network itself.

So, check <strike>firewall and antivirus</strike>, then internet connection, **then try to configure mongo to use only 127.0.0.1** same error 10050 with 127.0.0.1 configuration?

Comment: i turn off firewall and antivirus and still get the errno:10050

Comment: i configure mongo on localhost... still error... but i try in linux and the problem is windows